# How to create azure event hub topic programmatically in java?

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

I want to know the code/class used to create azure eventhub topics in java.

I searched and found that we can create using .Net like below.

```
var manager = new Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager("mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net");
var description = manager.CreateEventHub("MyEventHub");
```

I want the same for java..is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried googling "azure event hub java sdk"?

Comment: yes...but unable to figure out which class I need to import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my experience, you need to do two steps to create a namespace and an entity for Azure Event Hubs in Java, as below.

To create Namespaces:

1. Using Azure SDK for Java to create an EventHub namespace.

   First, add the dependency in the `pom.xml` file of Maven project.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
       <artifactId>azure</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   Here is my sample code using application token credential.

   ```
   String clientId = "<your client id regiested on AAD>";
   String domain = "<your talnet id or domain name>";
   String secret = "<your client key>";
   String subscription = "<your subscription id>";
   AzureTokenCredentials cred = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, domain, secret, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
   Azure azure = Azure.configure().authenticate(cred).withSubscription(subscription);

   String name = "<your eventhub namespace name>";
   String region = "<your eventhub region like 'East Asia'>";
   String resourceGroupName = "<your resource group name>";
   String resourceType = "namespaces";
   String providerNamespace = "Microsoft.EventHub";
   azure.genericResources().define(name).withRegion(region)
           .withExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName).withResourceType(resourceType)
           .withProviderNamespace(providerNamespace).withoutPlan()
           .create();
   ```
2. To create an EventHub namespace via the REST API [`Create Or Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/namespaces#Namespaces_CreateOrUpdate) of Event Hubs Namespaces in Java.

To create Entities:

1. Via the REST API [`Create Or Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/eventhubs#EventHubs_CreateOrUpdate) of Event Hubs in Java.
2. Via the REST API [`Create Event Hub`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/create-event-hub) of Entity management REST in Java.
3. Just create entity on Azure portal as the figure below.
   [image]

Otherwise, you can try to follow the document [`Create an EventHubs namespace, Event Hub, and consumer group`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-event-hubs-create-event-hub-and-consumer-group/) to create it via ARM template in Java with Azure SDK.

```
azure.deployments().define("<deployment-name>").withExistingResourceGroup("<resource-group-name>").withTemplate("<template-uri>").withParameters("<parameters required in the template>").withMode(DeploymentMode.COMPLETE).create();
```

Hope it helps.